# can I use a lat / long pair on a nodejs REST endpoint?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

my MEAN stack app is requesting user data based on a lon / lat coordinate. I currently send the coordinates via POST from an angularjs service to this expressjs route and handler:

```
getUsers = function(req, res) {
    var lonlat = req.body;

    // 2D spatial query
    return UserModelRef.find({'location': { $near: lonlat }}, function (err, data) {
         ...
}   

app.post('/user', getUsers);
```

This works but I'd prefer to do a GET along these lines:

```
getUsers = function(req, res) {
    var lonlat = req.params.location;

    // 2D spatial query
    return UserModelRef.find({'location': { $near: lonlat }}, function (err, data) {
        ...
}

app.get('/user/:location', getUsers);
```

but this request (http.get /user/-73.6398,40.7469) results in a Mongo error since the $near operator requires an object. Is there a way for the handler to convert the coordinates to an object that $near can use?

My goal is to treat the 2D coordinate pair like any other GET route parameter.

Comment: so what is preventing you splitting the string and creating the proper object before you make your query?

Comment: do you mean build a literal "[-73.6398,40.7469]" and use that?   example?

Comment: right, create whatever structure is needed for the query object